# Golang сервер на docker

Tags: nginx, golang, docker

Есть сервер написанный на Golang, на локалке собираю его в докер контейнере и работает он например на внешней порту 8080, на локалке проблем нету, но мне нужно это выкатить на прод и чтобы можно было на этот сервис дать запрос с другого сервера, например по домену и вот тут я не очень понимаю как это лучше сделать, можно проксировать Nginx'ом, но, как я понимаю, можно собрать контейнер с своим Nginx и там обрабатывать входящие запросы по домену. Подскажите, как это обычно делают?:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Свой контейнер с *nginx* можете не собирать, можете взять официальный (https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/) и написать `конфиг` для *nginx*, который пробросите через volume в официальный образ при запуске.